# Implementing Array.make in OCaml

Tags: arrays, module, shared-libraries, ocaml

I am trying to implement [Array.make](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Array.html) of the OCaml Array module. However I'm not getting the values right, my implementation:

```
 let make_diy s v = 
         let rec aux s v = 
           if s = 0 then [| |]
           else Array.append v ( aux (s-1) v )
       in aux s v;;
```

...has the value: `val make_diy : int -> 'a array -> 'a array = <fun>`instead of: `int -> 'a -> 'a array`. It only creates an array if `v` is already in an array:

```
make_diy 10 [|3|];;
- : int array = [|3; 3; 3; 3; 3; 3; 3; 3; 3; 3|]

make_diy 10 3;;
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         'a array
```

I also tried to make it with an accumulator, but it has the same result:

```
let make_diy s v = 
         let rec aux s v acc =  
           if s=0 then acc
           else append v ( aux (s-1) v acc  )
       in aux s v [| |];;
```

**EDIT: (typo) append instead of add**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `Array.append` expects two arrays. If you want to use it with just an element, you need to wrap the first argument into an array:

```
Array.append [| v |] (aux (s - 1) v)
```

Note that this isn't a particularly efficient way to build up an array. Each iteration will allocate a new, slightly larger array. But presumably this is just a learning exercise.

Comment: Thank you @Jeffrey Scofield.
How could I make it more efficient? There is no function to create an empty 'a array, create_float only works for float arrays.

Comment: `Array.make` is a primitive function of the array type, it cannot be implemented efficiently, outside of using `Array.make` itself (or the C FFI) directly.

Comment: Sure, but you could double the size of the array each time rather than adding 1 to its size.

Comment: @HeapUnderStop in general, `Array` is a more imperative data structure, so reason about it in a recursive way won't give great performances (except if you pass slices to the array, instead of an actual array, which is not the case here since you are building the array). The "right" way to do it (ie. have good performance) would be to make a single call to allocate the wanted size of the array, and then populate it. You can't really do that in OCaml (because it doesn't allow manual allocation), which is why it provides that data structure for you.